# Parsing JSON by Swift causes "...it isn’t in the correct format."

Tags: json, swift, macos

I want keep my objects structure in flat JSON dictionary `objects: [UUID:Any]` and later reconstruct relationships between them. So I build two structs one for encoding real objects and second to get data for reconstruction (*Managed isn't from CoreData, just similar name*). Generated JSON was OK, and everything worked nice and smooth, I could recreate objects structure, but when I added `GDGlyph.Parsed` very strange things start to happen. To see when it fails I added `CodingKeys` and `required init(from decoder: Decoder)`. When I try to read file:

```
{
  "objects": [
 
    "FDD4AF3F-1F95-41E5-9E26-6B20A31B9E86",
    {
      "glyph": {
        "name": ".notdef",
        "skinIDs": [],
        "controlIDs": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

by:

```
extension GDGlyph {
    
    class Parsed: ParsedClassProtocol {
        
        enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
            case controlIDs
            case skinsIDs
            case name
        }
        
        public var controlIDs : [UUID]
        public var skinIDs : [UUID]
        public var name: String
        
        required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            print ("try to init from decoder")
            print (decoder.codingPath)
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            print (name)
            self.controlIDs = try container.decode([UUID].self, forKey: .controlIDs)
            print (controlIDs)
            self.skinIDs = try container.decode([UUID].self, forKey: .skinsIDs)
            print (skinIDs)
            print ("DONE Glyph parsed")
        }
    }
}
```

parser stops and throws an error:

```
try to init from decoder
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "objects", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), ObjectCodingKeys(stringValue: "glyph", intValue: nil)]
.notdef
[]
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
```

It is not an only one object which has `[UUID]` array, but only this one make problems.

- With no `GDGlyph` everything works.
- When I remove `skinIDs` there is no error and I can read file
- When I remove `skinIDs` but add some `UUID` to `controlIDs` parser stops and throws. But looks it could read `GDGlyph`:

  try to init from decoder
  [CodingKeys(stringValue: "objects", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 3", intValue: 3), ObjectCodingKeys(stringValue: "glyph", intValue: nil)]
  A
  [28E14D0B-D74C-4311-A348-D3929AB0662C]
  DONE Glyph parsed
  OK CORRUPTED
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."

**Bit more about how I did it**:

Every object is saved via:

```
struct ManagedObjectEncoder : Encodable {

    var object: Managed
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys.self )
        for key in ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys.allCases {
           try? key.encode(object: object, container: &container)
        }
    }
}
```

and Dictionary `[UUID: ManagedObjectEncoder]`, and later read by:

```
struct ManagedObjectDecoder: Decodable {
    
    enum Errors: Error {
        case valueNotImplememted(Any)
    }
    
    var object: Any
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container =  try decoder.container(keyedBy: ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys.self)
        var proxy: Any? = nil
        for key in ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys.allCases {
            if let object = try key.decode(container: &container) {
                proxy = object
                break
            }
        }
        if let proxy = proxy {
            self.object = proxy
        } else {
            throw Errors.valueNotImplememted(container)
        }
    }
}
```

to `[UUID: ManagedObjectDecoder]`

Coding keys for every object in structure are defined...

```
extension ObjectsManager {
    enum ObjectCodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
    case value
    .... // Many  more
    case glyph
    }
}
```

...with extensions for Encode and Decode:

```
extension ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys {
    
    enum Errors:Error {
        case couldNotEncode(Managed)
    }
    
    func encode(object: Managed, container: inout KeyedEncodingContainer<ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys>
    ) throws {
        switch self {
        case .value:
            guard let value = object as? GDValue else
            {throw Errors.couldNotEncode(object)}
            try container.encode(value, forKey: self)
            
        .... // Many more 
      
        case .glyph:
            guard let value = object as? GDGlyph else
            {throw Errors.couldNotEncode(object)}
            try container.encode(value, forKey: self)
        }
    }
}

extension ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys {

    func decode(container: inout KeyedDecodingContainer<ObjectsManager.ObjectCodingKeys>
                
    ) throws -> ParsedClassProtocol? {
        switch self {
        case .glyph:
            print ("decode glyph")
            return try? container.decode( GDGlyph.Parsed.self, forKey: self)

        ....// Many more
        case .value:
            print ("decode value")
            return try? container.decode( GDValue.Parsed.self, forKey: self)
    }
}
```

I cannot guess a reason why it behave this way.

BTW: I when I save I got an error: `internal sandbox error for <StopAccessing>`

And full JSON:

```
  {
  "objects": [
    "52A5874F-3508-4228-83F8-EFCC5F733D01",
    {
      "value": {
        "locked": false,
        "valueType": "y",
        "name": "",
        "hyper": {
          "axesIDs": [],
          "vertices": [
            {
              "vertexType": 0,
              "data": 94.84832763671875,
              "coordinates": []
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "55F84CCA-69AF-42F6-86C9-DFECA9113940",
    {
      "glyph": {
        "name": "A",
        "controlIDs": [
          "28E14D0B-D74C-4311-A348-D3929AB0662C"
        ]
      }
    },
    "05D42155-2482-4EB8-8B2C-435B39DCC958",
    {
      "point": {
        "name": "",
        "xID": "FD248766-4334-4224-BF26-CB63A64EC07F",
        "yID": "52A5874F-3508-4228-83F8-EFCC5F733D01"
      }
    },
    "28E14D0B-D74C-4311-A348-D3929AB0662C",
    {
      "origin": {
        "name": null,
        "pointId": "05D42155-2482-4EB8-8B2C-435B39DCC958"
      }
    },
    "FD248766-4334-4224-BF26-CB63A64EC07F",
    {
      "value": {
        "locked": false,
        "valueType": "x",
        "name": "",
        "hyper": {
          "axesIDs": [],
          "vertices": [
            {
              "vertexType": 0,
              "data": 111.748291015625,
              "coordinates": []
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe it’s because in the last json in your post you have a glyph entry without a skinIDs entry although it isn’t optional

Comment: This JSON is from moment, when skinsIDs are removed from encoder, and (due to console output) GDGlyph is read. I have an output „DONE Glyph parsed” Error is thrown later.

Comment: Well your question is a mess with different json samples and way to much code, you need to clean it up and include only json and code that is relevant to your issue. Preferable with a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, it’s mess because I had no idea where to look for a bug and what information I should deliver. But you gave me very good hint I missed. Problem was in different object, where was nil instead “”. Seems to work now.